# How to decided CPU address is bit address or byte address?

Tags: embedded, cpu, microcontroller

I'm started learning 8051 microcontroller. In which I read about bit address and byte address. So, I have question, **How to decided CPU address is bit address or byte address?**

Comment: You must give more info, some example. Put like this, every number can be both a byte and bit address.

Comment: Why are you learning about an obsolete microcontroller from the 1980s?

Comment: You should search for it, but don't forget to add `8051` to your search, as this is absolute specific to this cpu

Comment: Also see [Embedded Systems/8051 Microcontroller](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Embedded_Systems/8051_Microcontroller). The term to search for is "bit addressable".

Answer (score 3):

Internal RAM between 0x20 and 0x2f is bit addressable along with some Special Function Registers (sfr's).

See http://www.edsim51.com/8051Notes/8051/memory.html for reference.